# Qt 6 - Create a tree representation of an xml document in Qt

Tags: c++, xml, qt

With QDom and the related libraries being deprecated, I want to achieve the same thing but without using QDom and related classes.  I want to take an xml file as input and make a tree-like structure for all the nodes.  I am not sure what Qt container to utilize or the complete algorithm, but I have started with the following code:

```
while (!xmlReader.atEnd() && !xmlReader.hasError()) {
    auto tokenType { xmlReader.readNext() };
    if (tokenType != QXmlStreamReader::StartElement)
        continue;
    }
}
```

Can someone help guide me in the right direction?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.